# How many times an element is repeated in a table

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a table which contains many records. I'm looking for an efficient way to count how many times an element is repeated.

Example table:

```
id     name
1      ana
2      john
3      tom
4      ana 
5      john
```

I've done so far , but it is inefficient.

```
$number  = 0;
for ($i =1 ; $i <= mysql_num_rows($query) ; $i++)
       for ($j = 1 ; $j <=mysql_num_rows($query); $j++)
           if ( $table[$i] == $table[$j])
                  $number++;
if ($number > 2 ) 
    echo $number;
```

Comment: Do you want SQL Query or php core logic

Comment: Is this table in a database? If so why not just use SQL to do it rather than doing it in code? (`select name, count(*) from table group by name` or similar).

Comment: Your loop(s) run in O(n²) runtime complexity … that's bad. You can count elements in O(n) linear time.

Comment: @knittl: I assume that's why the OP said that he is lookign for an efficient way and that what he has done is inefficient...

Comment: @user1127214 could you provide a php core logic ?

Comment: Either way, transferring all records and then count them in PHP will be inefficient, no matter what. Do a `COUNT`+`GROUPBY` on the sql server. All answers posted so far have proposed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly in SQL

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `name`
```

It will be more efficient, since you don't have to transfer every row to PHP.

Comment: You probably want to select the `name` as well; looks good otherwise.

Comment: can i use `count` in WHERE clause ?

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: `COUNT` aggregates values, if you want to filter the results after aggregating, you have to use the `HAVING` clause. e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) < 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1), name from table group by name;

count(1) name
2        ana
2        john
1        tom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it query side

```
select count(id), name from table group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the lowest id, name and how many times it exists:

```
select min(id),name,count(*) as cnt from table group by name
```

In a php array:

```
$newarray= array_count_values ( $table );
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_number_of_times_elements_occur_in_array($a)//returns values of array as keys,associating values being their total occurences in the array
{
$r=array();
foreach($a as $v)
    ++$r[$v];
return $r;
}
```

Access the returned array as per your needs.